# Prevent WhatsApp from automatically backing up messages

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

I noticed recently that WhatsApp automatically backups messages. I get a popup every now and then when I am using WhatsApp which says "*Backing up messages*". I don't want WhatsApp to backup my messages. I went into the WhatsApp settings and clicked '*Chats and calls -> Chat backup*' and it says:

```
Local: 3:00am
Google Drive: Never
```

Google Drive settings shows that my settings are set to '*Never back up to Google Drive*'.

With that said, how do I prevent it from backing up locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from WhatsApp FAQ [How do I restore my chat history](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/30003558)

> If your device is plugged into your computer at night, low on storage space or is set to sleep with no background data; WhatsApp will not be able to backup your chat history.

I presume freeing up storage space is your reason for not wanting to back up. To do that

- [How do I delete WhatsApp back up?](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/30030306) says

> Your Chat History Backup files are saved in the `/sdcard/WhatsApp/Databases/ folder`.- You cannot open these folders outside of WhatsApp.- Make sure you have a file manager to be able to delete these files...
>
> 1. Launch your File Manager.
> 2. Tap on the WhatsApp folder, a list of all WhatsApp sub-folders will appear.
> 3. Tap and hold the Databases file.
> 4. Select Delete.

- [Wcleaner for WA](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vAlmaraz.miniApp.WCleaner). App description amongst other features claims (not tested by me )

> Now you can delete or save WhatsApp backups (It is highly recommended not to delete latest backup)

Answer (score 7):

There's no way to do that. WhatsApp updates its backup at 4 am(for me, can vary) everyday locally for easy recovery of chats.

Comment: 'There is no way to do that'. You cannot prevent WhatsApp from taking backups, which is an answer to the question.

Comment: Oh okay. That was actually for another person who's comment seems to be deleted. Thanks.