# Whatsapp back up problem

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My Whatsapp is showing last back up in Google Drive as August 2  21:48 but after that it did not take any back up, and today's date is August 5, though   in google drive settings is showing as Backup to google drive as *daily*.

What needs to be done to ensure backup till today?

Comment: You can change the settings to *never*, then backup manually  to back up to Google Drive. But remember, whatsapp backup happens at 2 am every day. To see why daily backup did not happen , see this http://android.stackexchange.com/a/133105/131553

Comment: To clarify, 2 am backup is to the internal database stored on your device

Comment: Have you enabled Backup over Wi-Fi Only? If yes, and when Wi-Fi is not ON at a time when WhatsApp is trying to send back up to Google Drive, in that case your Backup will not be happening. This could be one of the possible reasons...